# My Circular bar graph looks messy when I add labels to its bars. Is there a way to make it look neat and clear?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a circular bar graph. When I add labels to the bars, it looks messy. Is there a way to make the labels look clear by changing the area of graph or something else. I'm unable to figure out how to do this. Please help me in this regard. Thanks for the help in advance.
This is my data;

```
structure(list(Corporations = c("Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", 
"Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck"
), Instruments = c("Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", "Bargeld", 
"Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen"), Q1.19 = c(NA, 6299, 555223, 2427, 32995, 
2189603, 56996, 31362, 1198580, 139931, 38424, 4340085, 3202446, 
60692, 2975850, 89437, 588297, 342623, NA, 230878, 2251130, 12242, 
1625426, 1255442, 2281472, 0, 30619, NA, 487, 319099, 6259, 38429, 
617751, 948, 41669, 99347, NA, NA, 62271, 1840, 15811, 92797, 
NA, 422, NA), Q2.19 = c(NA, 6454, 551837, 2085, 31926, 2198338, 
57709, 32616, 1178917, 148943, 39256, 4359950, 3303698, 60708, 
3056242, 89612, 726303, 358358, NA, 239382, 2284960, 12250, 1645940, 
1292362, 2297914, 0, 31502, NA, 487, 330817, 6150, 39239, 645949, 
954, -41925, 94741, NA, NA, 62626, 1839, 15866, 95467, NA, 362, 
NA), Q3.19 = c(NA, 6466, 573901, 2295, 32219, 2232079, 58430, 
32051, 1203447, 162442, 39311, 4261998, 3420453, 60885, 3157147, 
91016, 920818, 382937, NA, 249723, 2298254, 12225, 1667098, 1322047, 
2313450, 0, 32251, NA, 487, 330779, 6004, 42480, 676359, 960, 
-47370, 108842, NA, NA, 62854, 1913, 16052, 98454, NA, 480, NA
), Q4.19 = c(NA, 7386, 590593, 2183, 33011, 2317831, 59160, 31542, 
1229358, 161204, 44712, 4089901, 3332533, 60485, 3266643, 91257, 
761489, 440720, NA, 260243, 2337146, 12045, 1686127, 1383188, 
2331436, 0, 32043, NA, 487, 313552, 5315, 40097, 670891, 966, 
-42715, 104839, NA, NA, 61959, 1919, 16446, 103620, NA, 380, 
NA), Q1.20 = c(NA, 6742, 588896, 1979, 33086, 2103282, 59900, 
44907, 1178927, 173489, 49423, 4494126, 3354457, 61080, 2975370, 
90025, 1102066, 400057, NA, 279788, 2341738, 10748, 1703401, 
1220313, 2354882, 0, 31439, NA, 487, 350979, 5709, 41296, 664676, 
972, -44212, 115474, NA, NA, 62339, 1740, 16510, 94113, NA, 412, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is my code;

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Corporations, y = Q1.19, fill = Instruments)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(underline("Quartal 1, 2019")))) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red", size=2),
        legend.box.margin = margin(16, 6, 6, 6),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Q1.19, label = paste(Q1.19)), 
            size = 4, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.7))
```

Comment: Add `check_overlap = T` to `geom_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you, just try this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Corporations, y = Q1.19, fill = Instruments)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(underline("Quartal 1, 2019")))) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red", size=2),
        legend.box.margin = margin(16, 6, 6, 6),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Q1.19, label = paste(Q1.19)), 
            size = 4, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.7),check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you duck! However, after using check_overlap=T, some of the figures are not appearing in the graph now. Can you fix this?